# Hide() with fadeIn()/fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a fade in and fade out jquery.  However, I'm having some issues.

I hide the div when the page loads, but when I hover over it to fade it in, it fades in for a second then disappears.  I then have to hover out then hover back in.

My Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hidedsl6').hide();
    $('#showdsl6').hover(function(){
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeIn();
        }, function(){
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#showfttn10').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn15').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn25').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn50').hover(function(){
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<h3 class="DSLLocation" id="showdsl6">DSL 6</h3>
<button class="btn btnblue" id="hidedsl6" type="button">Order Now!</button>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/efwj8L6r/1/

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: @Mihai That solved it, can you please put as an answer so I can accept it.

Thanks for the help everyone!

I didn't know duplicate ID's would cause an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use jQuery when **it can be done with CSS**

```css
.products{
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.option{
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
  background: #C0FFEE;
}
.option button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1CEA6E;
  transition: 0.3s; -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.option:hover button{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">

  <div class="option">
    <h3>DSL 6</h3>
    <button>ORDER NOW!</button>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <h3>DSL 30</h3>
    <button>ORDER NOW!</button>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <h3>SUPER DSL 50</h3>
    <button>ORDER NOW!</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add preventDefault to stop the back and forth fade

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hidedsl6').hide();
    $('#showdsl6').hover(function(){
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeIn();
        }, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hidedsl6').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#showfttn10').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn15').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn25').hover(function(){
    });
    $('#showfttn50').hover(function(){
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#hidedsl6').hide();

      $('#showdsl6').hover(function(){
      $('#hidedsl6').fadeIn();});


});
```